# Lamp holder for bicycle stem

Tags: lighting

Is there any lamp holder for the bicycle stem?
The normal 360º degrees spinning lamp holders do not work, because the stem is slightly top-wards inclined.

**Bike stem**

[image]

**Normal lamp holder**

[image]

Comment: Not an answer - but consider hanging your thing under the handlebars... for a front light it doesn't really matter.  Helmet lights are good, but they don't replace the need for handlebar lights.

Comment: @Criggie is right but you may have to watch the cables under the bars, and tie them out of the way. Doesn't solve handlebar bag issues though and a tall enough stem mount might.

Comment: @Criggie, I don't use helmet, it is for urban cycling. The handlebars are fully occupied with cables and brakes.

Comment: @joao_pimentel  I'm sorry to hear that.   Perhaps you could try putting a head torch on?   Personally I've found that a small sharp tight beam torch on the head works well at night, for lighting up stuff /drivers exactly where I'm looking.   Has saved me from being doored at least once.

Comment: Brands like topeak sell bar extenders, which can be clamped to the stem: http://www.topeak.com/products/xtras/barxtender

Comment: http://www.hopetech.com/hope-vision/

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like [this](http://www.ebay.de/itm/Fahrradlampe-Taschenlampe-Scheinwerfer-Halterung-fur-Fahrrad-Computer-Handy-Neu-/381320092465?var=&hash=item58c872db31:m:msRQGjl7ynXtw13mQfxBbNQ) may do the work?

[image]

But I couldn't find anything around the stem.

Comment: Anyone recommend to use two, one of each side?

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to go to the very cheap end of the spectrum, some lights can pivot in the mount as well as having a hinge for tilt. [This awful thing from deal extreme](http://www.dx.com/p/waterproof-6-led-2-mode-white-light-cycling-bike-light-w-holder-black-silvery-white-402472), for example, runs on two watch batteries but does what you want:

[image]

Alternatively, some of the "flashlight holders" are very adaptable (and probably also flexible) so would work. [Like this construction](http://www.dx.com/p/fat-cat-m-fb3-3-in-1-bike-mount-adapter-flashlight-holder-phone-clamp-for-gopro-hero-4-more-364357):

[image]

Finally, you can make something yourself by using hose clamps:

[image]

One round the stem, then another around the light or use a strip of metal to make a mount for the light. I've made light mounts like this before and they can be very effective. Buy a strip of aluminium about 3mm thick and 20mm wide, then cut and drill a short length to do what you need. Imagine the blue line is a strip of aluminium and the red bar is your light.

[image]

But really, a much better solution is [joao_pimentel's answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/35392/7044). A decent metal "need more handlebar space" device as sold in many bike shops specifically because so many people have the same problem you do.

Comment: Jubilee clips are fantasticly useful - I have a couple holding a water bottle cage on, but they're ready to serve in another capacity as required.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to go to the cheap version. Is there anything that allows tilt, more robust and with better quality? How would I connect those two hoses ties?

Comment: I couldn't find a better solution except for cameras, and they are ridiculously expensive because you're buying functionality that you don't need (over $US1000 for a decent action camera mounting system).

Comment: Edited in "how to use hose clamps".

Answer (score 2):

I've used 2 light brackets with bits of a third to make custom brackets before. I have a large spares box and a decent selection of tools for modifications.

In your case a saddle post light bracket might fit round them stem giving you something to pick up on to mount your light.

On eBay or dx you can find a wide range of torch mounts, smartphone mounts and camera mounts for various bits of bikes. The camera ones in particular may be a good source of parts with enough degrees of freedom. You'll need to modify though.